# msedge - get feedback for horizontal tab groups

Tags: navigation, tabs, browser, collapsing

#### Vertical tabs in [browser](/questions/tagged/browser) edge

Currently [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) has vertical tabs

[image: msedge vertical tabs]

#### Proposal for horizontal tabs

I would love to have the groups as normal horizontal tabs. Each Group would render one tab. Clicking on a `group-tab` would expand (toggle collapse) all pages as normal tabs next to the `group-tab`.

With three `group-tabs` the layout should look like this

```
   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
   | Group-1   Tab 1  Group-2 Group-3  Tab 8  Tab 24   Tab 7 
   | ________________         ______________________________
   |
   |
```

Above `Group-1`  and `Group-3` are expanded. Therefore all `page-tabs` below Group-1 and 3 are visible. The Tab `Group-2` is collapsed: therefore `page-tabs` are not visible.

To save some space the Name of a `group-tab` could be shortened if the group is expanded (`Pla`,`Sup`). Only for collapsed `group-tabs` (like `Edge_Devel` below) the full name is displayed:

```
   |-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
   | Pla   Tab 1  Edge_Devel Sup  Tab 8  Tab 24   Tab 7 
   | ___________             ______________________________
   |
   |
```

Related but not relevant for my question

- [horizontal vs vertical tabs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8207/horizontal-vs-vertical-tabs)
- [Vertical tabs to horizontal tabs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/133158/vertical-tabs-to-horizontal-tabs)

#### Question

Do you have any suggestions how to improve my proposal for horizontal tabs?

Comment: See also [Feature suggestions for tab groups](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/2be2b04d-e5ef-ec11-a81b-000d3a00c008) and [better tab groups](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/65023321-6d9c-ec11-a81c-00224850e48f)

Comment: From what I understand, Edge still has support for grouped horizontal tabs. I would suggest that you start by figuring out in which ways their implementation of grouped tabs could be improved upon.

Answer (score 0):

As [ro-achterberg](https://ux.stackexchange.com/users/134308/) pointed out ms-edge has a feature that is implemented similar to what is described above.

Below you can see three `tab-groups`

- `ux echange` is the first group and has one tab
- `Edge_Developer` is the 2nd tab group and is collapsed. It contains two tabs (not visible)
- `Superuser` is the 3r tab group and collapsed as well.

[image: edge horizontal tab-groups]

Comment: So where does that you leave you with your original question?

Comment: I would a) either accept my own answer (as soon as i can) or if you prefer b) i delete my question.